# How to draw a square wave using ZedGraph?

Tags: c#, .net, zedgraph

How to draw square wave using [ZedGraph](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page)?

I'm thinking about something like this:

[alt text http://www.zsee.bytom.pl/sciaga/prad/grafika/okr%20prosto.jpg](http://www.zsee.bytom.pl/sciaga/prad/grafika/okr%20prosto.jpg)

My formula is:

```
y =  amplitude, if sin(x) >=0

y = -amplitude, if sin(x) < 0
```

In theory it should give a square wave, but gives me:

[alt text http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/9813/xxxmy.png](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/9813/xxxmy.png)

Comment: One formula for this is x=sign(sin(T)).

Comment: I have got a formula that should work, but I'm troubled with this vertical direction curve at T and 1/2 T

Comment: just to be clear, you're not getting the correct values? or, You're getting the correct values and zedGraph isn't drawing them?

Comment: //I'm getting the correct values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change the step type of your curve. Use:

```
line.Line.StepType = StepType.ForwardStep;
```

of course `line` is your `LineItem` object

Comment: For reference: the other step type is `StepType.RearwardStep`. A demo can be found at: http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Smooth_Chart_Demo

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's stepping at discrete values along the X axis (which is really almost unavoidable), and drawing a steep (but still visibly non-vertical) line from the last point at which it sampled a positive sin(x), through sin(x)=0 to the next point at which it sample a negative sin(x).

The obvious cure is to tell it to sample the function at smaller intervals -- specifically, small enough so the transition from +1 to -1 (or vice versa) happens in less than the width of a pixel as you'll end up displaying it.

Comment: But it's not the solution, it is only fake, cheating our eye's perception. After zooming in, it will be still visible. 
You should change the step type for your curve (LineItem):
line.Line.StepType = StepType.ForwardStep;